# Radio Button android

Tags: android, radio-button, drawable

Can anyone explain me why does this happen?
I have 3 radio buttons with 3 diferent imagens. for each radio button i've created a drawable with a selector for when the radio button is checked and when it's not. It's working perfectly and on the eclipse, but on the emulator it doenst work well.

Here's the images.

On eclipse:

[image: On eclipse]

On Emulator:

[image: On Emulator]

here's the code:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonSmallBag"
        style="@style/radioButtonStyle"
        android:checked="true"
        android:button="@drawable/small_bag_selector"/>

    <RadioButton
         android:id="@+id/radioButtonMediumBag"
         style="@style/radioButtonStyle"
         android:button="@drawable/medium_bag_selector" />

    <RadioButton
         android:id="@+id/radioButtonBigBag"
         style="@style/radioButtonStyle"
         android:button="@drawable/big_bag_selector" />
</RadioGroup>
```

The style:

```
<style name="radioButtonStyle">
<item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
<item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
<item name="android:layout_marginRight">5dp</item>
</style>
```

A drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
       android:state_checked="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/trip_small_bag_selected"/>
<item 
   android:state_checked="false"
   android:drawable="@drawable/trip_small_bag"/>
 </selector>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: exactly what do you mean by "it doesn't work well" ?

Comment: it doesnt work well because when running the app on the emulator, it cuts the images of the radio buttons by half.i've uploaded the picture of the emulator

Comment: It seems like your layout is been pushed out by some other view, making it smaller, losing weight some how.
I would say that you are not posting the whole XML file that contains the radiogroup.
?Are you setting the size of the views programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this answer about resolutions: [Android resolutions and emulator not choosing correct image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774232/android-resolutions-and-emulator-not-choosing-correct-image)

And Supporting Mult Screen : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources

Comment: i have different dpi images of each drawable. for each image i have a 320dpi version, a 240dpi version and a 160dpi version, but still, it doenst work...

Comment: could the radio buttons have a limite size for an image?

Comment: Be sure you've created directories for each DPI(hdpi, ldpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi). After, verify your Emulator DPI.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running an emulator with a different `DPI`. You should provide different image sizes to be used on different `DPI` screens, for example, on an `MDPI` phone, you may wanna use an image, lets say, `100x100 px`. Then the same image goes to `HDPI` but at `175x175 px`. Then for `HDPI` you go for `200x200 px`. Read http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources for further info

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why this happens but if i put some text it works but with the text behing the radio button.

This code:

```
<RadioButton
     android:id="@+id/radioButtonSmallBag"
     style="@style/radioButtonStyle"
     android:checked="true"
     android:button="@drawable/small_bag_selector"/>
```

resulted in this:

[image: wrong]

but this code:

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButtonSmallBag"
    style="@style/radioButtonStyle"
    android:checked="true"
    android:button="@drawable/small_bag_selector"
    android:text="hiiiiiii"/>
```

resulted in:

[image: almost correct]

this is why i think the radio button has a limit size. so i had this crazy idea and i did this:

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButtonSmallBag"
    style="@style/radioButtonStyle"
    android:checked="true"
    android:background="@drawable/small_bag_selector"
    android:button="@null"/>
```

it's working and doing what i want.
Here it is:

[image: correct]